# Can I know when a specific commit reached master branch?

Tags: git

I can see the git log. 
The `commits` timestamps are for when they were committed on the feature branch.

]Can I know what datetime where that commit **merged/rebased to master branch?**

The context here is that I want to know if a certain commit has "reached" production.

For example, if I committed 3 days to `feature branch`, deployed 2 days ago to production from `master`, and rebased to `master` from  1 day ago, then it's **not** there. **But** if it's been 2 months since I last deployed and I just view the commit logs, I see that that code should be in production.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the branch was merged, then the timestamp on the merge commit is what you want.  If it was a fast-forward, there's no merge commit.  If you want to ensure that you always have a merge commit, impost a policy that forbids fast-forward merges. (eg, always merge with `--no-ff`)

Comment: But it sounds like what you really need is a release process!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given something like;

[image]

You want;

```
$ git log --merges feature..master
commit 1164f67c574e52d3c25b89a76fbac2ce03685e06 (tag: MergeOfInterest)
Merge: 4ea723c e8d172a
Date:   Tue Jul 31 13:11:50 2018 +0100

Merge branch 'feature'
```

Or;

```
$ git log --merges feature..master --pretty=format:"%ci"
2018-07-31 13:11:50 +0100
```

For just the date.